# Detecting Mobile Networks via HTTP

Tags: html, http, mobile, mobile-website, 3g

Is there any way to identify if an HTTP request originated from a mobile network (3G/4G/Edge)?  Do wireless carriers typically append any request headers? Or are there known IP ranges?

For example, I'd like to distinguish between an iOS request over wifi vs 3G or a desktop browser through a hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do that on the server by itself.

There was a recent [addition](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/commit/1b46a13e4ddff9dd0f9972f377a67cfdef0e20b1#diff-0) to Modernizr to determine the bandwidth type of the connection. You can use that client side and pass the result on to the server.